# Simple model gets 0.0 accuracy

Tags: tensorflow

I am training a simple model on a dataset containing labels always equal to 0, and am getting a 0.0 accuracy.

The model is the following:

```
import csv
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf

labelsReader = pd.read_csv('data.csv',usecols = [12],header=None)
dataReader = pd.read_csv('data.csv',usecols = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11],header=None)

labels_ = labelsReader.values
data_ = dataReader.values

labels = np.float32(labels_)
data = np.float32(data_)

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 11])
W = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([11, 1], stddev=1./11.))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1]))
y = tf.matmul(x, W) + b

# Define loss and optimizer
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1])

cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y_, logits=y))
train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5).minimize(cross_entropy)

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
tf.global_variables_initializer().run()

for i in range(0, 1000):
    train_step.run(feed_dict={x: data, y_: labels})

correct_prediction = tf.equal(y, y_)
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
print(sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: data, y_: labels}))
```

And here is the dataset:

```
444444,0,0,0.9993089149965446,0,0,0.000691085003455425,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

As the model trains, y of the data shown above decreases, and reaches -1000 after 1000 iterations.

What could be the cause of the failure to train the model ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your accuracy checks if the predicted float is exactly equal to the value you expect. With the network you made this is a very difficult task (although you might have a chance as you are also overfitting your data).

To get better results: 
- Define accuracy to be higher/lower than a value (closer to 1 or closer to 0). 
- Normalise your input data, I don't know the range of your input, but 444444 is a rediculous value to use as input, and it is difficult to train weights that can handle these values.

Also: try to add some sanity checks. For example: what is the output your model is predicting? (y.eval) And what is the cross entropy you have during training your network? (sess.run([accuracy,cross_entropy], feed_dict={x: data, y_: labels})

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the value 444444 isn't actually used, it is not in the "usecols". As for the cross entropy, it is always 0 as is accuracy. The model predicts negative numbers that decrease as the training advances.